# Is it acceptable to edit an answer that's already accepted

Tags: support

My [answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/342141/estimating-time-costs-in-legacy-codebase/342145#342145) has the highest score (79 at time of posting) and has been accepted by the questioner.  (Thanks!)

I'm a little unhappy with it though, and a couple of commenters have made valid points that I'd like to address.  What I don't want to do is breach etiquette.

I'm not proposing a total re-write, just a bit of correction and rewording as well as adding a couple of points suggested by others in comments (with attribution of course).

Is this acceptable, intended behaviour by an author of an answer or is it distorting seeing as so many people have kindly up-voted me already?

Advice gratefully received.

Answer (score 6):

Sure it is acceptable, especially if it is just "a bit of correction and rewording". The goal of this site is to produce excellent questions & answers, and doing improvements to both at any time is part of the process. If there are comments below an answer mentioning things which should be corrected, it is much easier for later readers if they do not have to scan through the whole comments section to find these additional corrections.

For the unlikely case someone is not happy with those changes, he/she can write another comment, and you can then decide if you revert the changes or not. For the hypothetical case you change the meaning of your answer in a way the asker does not like your answer any more after the change, he can also accept a different answer at any time (but I would not expect that happen in your case).

Comment: Thanks, I thought so but I didn't want to upset people